# What can i input to console to trigger this button in this list?

Tags: jquery, html

What can i type in console to choose the IMDb rating without pressing
any buttons? preferably something in jQuery. Right now this is the
best i came up with:

```
$('.btnSort.button-flat.listTextButton-autohide.emby-button').trigger("click");
$('.listItem.listItem-button.actionSheetMenuItem.emby-button[data-id="CommunityRating,SortName"]').trigger("click");
```

But it requires me to input two codes, and I can't input them at the
same time. So what can I enter?
I also tried this

```
$('.btnSort.button-flat.listTextButton-autohide.emby-button').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
```

But then [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoGU.png) happens, it does not seem to trigger the button in the list.

```
<button is="emby-button" class="btnSort button-flat listTextButton-autohide emby-button">
<span class="btnSortText">THIS BUTTON BRINGS UP THE OTHER BUTTONS</span>
<i class="md-icon btnSortIcon button-icon button-icon-right"></i>
</button>

<!–– When I click the button with the HTML above this line
----------------------------------------------------------
The buttons with the HTML listed down below comes up   ––>


<div class="focuscontainer dialog actionSheet opened" data-lockscroll="true" data-history="true" data-autofocus="true" data-removeonclose="true" style="position: fixed; left: 405.086px; top: 10px;">
  <h2 class="actionSheetTitle">Sort by:</h2>
  <div is="emby-scroller" data-horizontal="false" data-centerfocus="card" class="actionSheetScroller actionSheetScroller-withheader emby-scroller scrollY">
    <div class="scrollSlider flex flex-direction-column"><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="CriticRating,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Critic rating</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="DateCreated,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Date added</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="DatePlayed,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Date played</div>
        </div>
      </button><button autofocus="" is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem actionSheetMenuItem-selected emby-button" data-id="CommunityRating,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">IMDb rating</div>
        </div>
        <div class="listItemAside actionSheetItemAsideText"><i class="md-icon"></i></div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="OfficialRating,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Parental rating</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="PlayCount,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Play count</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="PremiereDate,ProductionYear,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Release date</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="Runtime,SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Runtime</div>
        </div>
      </button><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="listItem listItem-button actionSheetMenuItem emby-button" data-id="SortName"><i class="actionsheetMenuItemIcon listItemIcon listItemIcon-transparent md-icon secondaryText" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
        <div class="listItemBody actionsheetListItemBody">
          <div class="listItemBodyText actionSheetItemText">Title</div>
        </div>
      </button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="actionSheet-bottom"><button is="emby-button" type="button" class="btnCloseActionSheet btnCloseActionSheet-default hide-mouse-idle-tv raised block emby-button">Cancel</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the issue having to run two lines of code?

Comment: I want to automate things with tampermonkey, and my whole automation script so far runs with no delays, and if i want to run those two codes i need to input a delay between them and then i have to think about pageload times and so on.

Comment: Also if this worked $('.btnSort.button-flat.listTextButton-autohide.emby-button').prop('selectedIndex', 3); it would be a much more elegant solution. I can't figure out why it doesn't, because it should.

Comment: well sounds like the form is not activated until it is shown.

Comment: Yeah i thought so too but if i manually click first button so the list with the other buttons shows and then i enter the jQuery above i still get the same message in console with no result.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoGU.png